# Reference request: A lawyer's take on the novel _Starman Jones_?

Tags: reference-request, law-in-fiction, morality

A lawyer named James Stone has a Youtube channel on which he posts his analyses of movies that involve legal matters – usually civil or criminal lawsuits. I've wondered about a lawyer's take on a certain novel and as far as I know he hasn't done those.

Has anything been published – a book review or any sort of essay – in which a lawyer has analyzed this story from a lawyer's point of view?

The events take place after laws forbid entry into high-paying professions without inheriting a union membership, and they forbid working in most respectable jobs without paying an apprentice fee to join a union. Setting the story in the future means the laws of intestate succession, which play a role, and some other things, may differ from what exists now, but one thing that hasn't changed since 1953 (the date of publication) is rigid traditional gender roles: **all** husbands support their wives.

The story has a really unusually high incidence of explicit discussion of legal and moral issues, but done in such a way that those don't interrupt the adventure-story nature of the novel, in part by being focused sharply on the application of those issues to the protagonist's situation.

The novel is *Starman Jones* by Robert Heinlein. The protagonist fraudulently claims a record of service as a crewman on ships that transport passengers and freight, and membership in the requisite union, in order to get another such job.

> His father had told him, when he knew he was dying, “Take care of your mother, son.” Well, he had done so. He had made a crop every year—food in the house and a little money, even if things had been close. When the mule died, he had made do, borrowing McAllister's team and working it out in labor.
>
> But had Dad meant that he had to take care of his stepmother even if she remarried? It had never occurred to him to consider it. Dad had told him to look out for her and he had done so, even though it had put a stop to school and did not seem to have any end to it.
>
> But she was no longer Mrs. Jones but Mrs. Montgomery. Had Dad meant for him support Mrs. Montgomery?
>
> Of course not! When a woman married, her husband supported her.  Everybody knew that. And Dad wouldn't expect him to put up with Montgomery. He stood up, his mind suddenly made up.

and later:

> The library book had been burning a hole in his rucksack; at Oklahoma City he noticed a postal box near the freight depot and, on impulse, dropped the book into it. After he had mailed it he felt a twinge of worry that he might have given a clue to his whereabouts that would get back to Montgomery, but he suppressed the worry—the book *had* to be returned. Vagrancy in the eyes of the law had not worried him, nor trespass, nor impersonating a licensed teamster—but filching a book was a sin.

And it becomes important that the laws in force aboard a ship go wherever the ship goes. And then later:

> Mr. Jones, a ship is not just steel, it is a delicate political entity whose laws and customs cannot be disregarded without inviting disaster.

A published analysis by an expert on both law and morality would be exactly what I wonder about but maybe that's a long shot. A book review by a lawyer commenting specifically on the legalities would also be responsive.

Comment: There are potential legal issues in the book, and Heinlein is known for his thought experiments with law and cultural norms. But, as written, this question is too broad, and too opinion based. Also, this SE is primarily about what the law is, not what it might be and definitely what not what it should be. There is a place for legal theory, but this really goes beyond that.

Comment: @ohwilleke : This is to be read as a reference request: Has such a thing been published, in a blog or a youtube video or a book review, etc. That's not opinion-based.

Comment: To the "close" voter: the question is clearly stated in the third sentence. It asks if a work of a certain type (a legal analysis of _Starman Jones_) has been published. The answer can only be "yes" or "no." How is this opinion-based?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Question has been changed and clarified since my original comment and close vote. I agree that in current form it is an on topic reference request.

Comment: As something of an aside, it is a hard question to answer, because, despite the fact that the U.S. spends years of college prep track students' lives teaching them to produce literary criticism, and produces many tens of thousands of English majors each year with the same skill set, exceedingly little literary criticism beyond short book reviews in news periodicals do it, very few people consume it, and what is done isn't easily accessible.

Comment: Searching for any review is not stack compatible. Searching for a very specific review or item would be (I read a law review that had the case X, Y and Z in it and was talking about how OSHA by an MIT professor - what was that?)